# Pending unfriendly flags missing from main flag history page

Tags: bug, user-interface, comment-flags, welcoming, flag-history

I just raised my first "unfriendly" flag. It shows up in my *comment* flag history, at https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1709587?group=4...

[image: Screenshot showing the above]

... but it's missing from my main flag history at https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1709587, and there's no "pending" comments section available for me to select in the right-hand sidebar:

[image: Screenshot showing the above]

This seems broken; these flags ought to be shown just like other comment flags in the flagging history.

Comment: Cross-site dupe on Meta.SE: ['Unfriendly or unkind' flag not showing in flag summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313806/289905).

Comment: Aha, yes - according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313756/200582, there's a fix already rolling out.